# Prime numbers dividing infinitely many 9-repunits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $p$ is a prime different from 2 and 5, prove that $p$ divides infinitely many of the integers 9, 99, 999…

Can I please be provided a detailed explanation of it because I have many a times been stuck in this type of question.

Answer (score 2):

These numbers are $10^n-1$, so the question is "are there infinitely many
$n$ with $p\mid(10^n-1)$", equivalently "are there infinitely many
$n$ with $10^n\equiv1\pmod p$". Now, what do you know about congruence
modulo a prime $p$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. The numbers are of the form $10^n-1$. Use [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem): if $a$ is not divisible by $p$, then $p$ divides $a^{p-1}-1$.

Answer (score 1):

First, since $p$ is not $2$ or $5$, we know $gcd(p,10)=1$. Thus, by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we know that
$$10^{p-1}\equiv 1\ (mod\ p).$$

Thus, for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, we know
$$(10^{p-1})^k\equiv 1^k\ (mod\ p)$$
$$10^{k(p-1)}\equiv 1\ (mod\ p).$$

This implies $p$ divides $10^{k(p-1)}-1$. However, note that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $10^{k(p-1)}-1\in\{9,99,999,...\}$

We conclude $p$ divides infinitely many members of $\{9,99,999,...\}$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know Fermat's little theorem, usr the pigeon-hole principle: There are only $p$ possible remainders mod $p$, hence among the $p+1$ numbers $1,10,\ldots, 10^p$, there must be two $10^i, 10^j$, $0\le i<j\le p$, with the same remainder. It follows that $p\mid 10^j-10^i=10^i(10^{j-i}-1)$. Then as $p\nmid 10$, it follows that $p\mid10^{j-i}-1$, so there is at least one $n>0$ with $p\mid 10^n-1$. But there cannot be a largest such $n$, for $p\mid 10^n-1$ implies $p\mid (10^n-1)(10^n+1)=10^{2n}-1$.